# Calculating Line Density in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, density

I have a map of fracture distributions over an area and I would like to calculate the density distribution of fractures that intersect a moving window with a specified radius.

Is there a way to calculate this in QGIS, similar to the line density calculation in ArcGIS Spatial Analysis?

Answer (score 6):

Since the release of QGIS 3.12 you can use the native `Line Density` algorithm from the processing toolbox. It is implemented in C++ and is a 1:1 port of the Line Density tool that is available in the ArcGIS toolbox. 
[image]

For more information on the exact calculation of the line density measure you can have a look at the [pull request on Github](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/33525).

Answer (score 5):

Not in QGIS, but I can throw out two suggestions using other tools (thru QGIS plugins).
The procedure in GRASS is to convert the line to points and run v.kernel on the points. The other (probably better) way is to import the line into R, load the spatstat package and use the density.psp() function.

Both tips were mentioned already on the [grass-users](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/calculating-road-density-td3898108.html) maillist.