# Making map where overlapping symbols increase Opacity?

Tags: cartography, software-recommendations, overlapping-features

I was looking at some maps like: [Map from Ship Logs](http://bigthink.com/strange-maps/636-painted-ships-on-painted-oceans-an-accidental-map-of-the-doldrums) [image: Map]

or the [Facebook worldwide friendships Mapped](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=469716398919) (via the [Flowing Data](http://flowingdata.com/2010/12/13/facebook-worldwide-friendships-mapped/) blog)
[image]

These Maps look good because single lines are almost transparent, and as more and more lines are drawn, the opacity goes up, and you get patterns only with lines where multiple lines are present.

I have some data of Bus Routes in shapefile format, and would like to do something similar from this.

Which software will allow me to do this? Which software can create this effect?

Comment: I think you can do it in QGIS using a conjuntion of layer transparency, layer blending mode and symbol transparency. But I would have to try it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do it in [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org) using symbol transparency, feature blending mode and symbol color.

Notice the difference between Layer Transparency and blending mode(that will be applied to all features) and the symbol transparency and feature blending mode that will stack with other features in the same layer.

All seetings are available in **Layers Properties** > **Style**.

[image]

With the value of 95% of symbol transparency, the chosen color for the line will be totally opaque only when at least 20 features overlay each other. This number is limited to a 100 features overlay (tranparency 99%).

**UPDATE:** Following [Nathan](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/97/nathan-w) advice, using different blending modes (like multiply and addition) other effects can be achieved.

[image]

Duplicating the layer, with different line colors and using modes like dodge in the layer blending, can give some nice effects.

[image]

Comment: I'm still thinking about how to do the second image, going from blue (or other color) to white. Any ideas of how to do it in QGIS?

Comment: You should use feature blending for this.  Will work much better.

Comment: @NathanW Isn't blending only available at layer level? It will apply to the all layer, and will not have the desired efect. OR I am missing something?

Comment: Nope, layer and feature level.  `Feature blending mode`.  Even in your first screenshot :)

Comment: Go with 50% blue and turn on subtract blending mode.

Comment: Forget it! I found it in the meanwhile :-P

Comment: With a dark background and `Addition` you will get this: http://i.imgur.com/tuGiKpc.png

Comment: The first image can be done with `Multiply`

Comment: Resuming, +1 for QGIS for having lots of available tools for creating "increasing opacity maps" in a very straightforward way.

Comment: I would update your pictures using the blend modes because they match the intention better.

Comment: Good update. :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure for the first example, but the second one is an image of the line density (a raster data created based on a kernel that produces an weighted sum of the lines in a neighborhood).

in practice, you can do it with [arcgis](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000000t000000.htm) line density (spatial analyst) and you will find open source hints [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24532/how-to-calculate-line-density-in-qgis)

EDIT: the first example was thus well lines with a feature transparency. This is not feasible in ArcGIS (you can set feature transparency for polygons, but it does not add to each other for overlapping polygons of the same layer. In theory, of course, you could make one layer per line...). So +1 for QGIS...

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this in Tilemill using the following:

```
line-comp-op: plus;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in ArcGIS, albeit without advanced blending modes: Use "Symbol Levels" under "Advanced" in the "Symbology" tab and use a field for transparency.